# <iframe> Border removing, using inline script which is included within file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

we have index.html in which second.html is included using iframe,
Now, as we see the iframe border in index.html

Requirement here is **we need to write inline script in second.html**, so that while rendering second.html in index.html, it'll remove iframe border.
we are not allowed to make any changes in that page where iframe included i.e. index.html

```
 <div class="external">
    <iframe src="/folder/second.html" width="100%" height="700"></iframe>
</div>
```

please suggest me the approach to remove iframe border using the file which is included in html using iframe
Sample Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code

```
  <iframe src="/folder/second.html" style="border:none;"height:700px;width:100%"><iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iframe is used to show other content in our web page. You can show videos,images and other web pages in Iframes.

You cannot make any changes in renderer for security reasons.

If that happened....then,

scripts, styles and all parts of both web pages will mix and will change design and functioning of both pages

You cannot change border of iframe from `second.html`. You should make changes in `index.html`:

```
<iframe style="border:0;"></iframe>
```

However you can [make changes in some rendering pages of iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument2)